# NestJS + Fastify e2e testing: Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing, fastify, nestjs-fastify

While running end-to-end tests of NestJS+Fastify application I noticed the following warnings:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

My code follows the docs:
[image]

When adding the `--detectOpenHandles` option I saw the following:

```
 FAIL  test/app.e2e-spec.ts
  AppController (e2e)
    ✕ /GET cats (975 ms)

  ● AppController (e2e) › /GET cats

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 200
    Received: 404

      23 |       })
      24 |       .then((result) => {
    > 25 |         expect(result.statusCode).toEqual(200);
         |                                   ^
      26 |         expect(result.payload).toEqual('API is running.');
      27 |       });
      28 |   });

      at app.e2e-spec.ts:25:35
```

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The pasted example is incomplete, application has to be closed manually just like in the Express example:

```js
  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
```

And the warning is gone. Also created a [PR to improve NestJS' docs](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2112).